# orientational metaphor: I'm feeling "up" today

Tags: phrases, sense-verbs

I have come across the following as examples of "orientational metaphors":

**happy is up**; **sad is down**:

> I'm feeling up today. He's really low these days.

While I understand the general concept, I do wonder if native speakers of English commonly use "I'm feeling up today" in daily conversations to express their (temporary) sense of well-being.

Comment: 'down' is more commonly expressed, but 'up' works just fine.

Comment: They're not the [only words used](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), either.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't hear 'up' used in general conversation. The use of 'down' to indicate sadness or depression is quite a lot more common.

'High' is in occasional use but it generally refers to artificially imposed moods.